# Model returns relation´s dynamic attributes but null relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship, mass-assignment

I have set 2 models (Post and Category) with it´s proper relationships configured

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'excerpt',
        'body',
        'featured',
        'published',
        'category_id',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

And my Post´s storing method is

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = Post::create($request->all());
    return redirect('admin/posts');
}
```

The thing is, it´s actually working ok, it sets the `category_id` on the table and I can fetch all the dynamic data by using `$post->category->name`, but when I `var_dump($post->relation)` I get a `null` return.

I if create a new Post model, set all the attributes, save it and then associate the Category model (as documented on the official channel), it will return everything as expected.

For now, all I need is to fetch it´s dynamic attributes, and it´s working fine now, but I know I must be doing something wrong to get the null response. My concern is that it may be working fine now, but when the project gets larger I´ll probably face a bigger problem and I´ll have a lot of work to fix this issue.

Comment: You mean `var_dump($post->category)` ?

Comment: No, I really meant `dd($post->category->name);`. I do get what´s expected like this, which is the post´s category name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation isn't there because you haven't loaded it.  All it knows is the foreign key.  It would be wildly inefficient if it grabbed all that information for you because it wouldn't always need all that.  Think of instances where a single model could have many relationships, that would be many database calls for no reason.

If you need the relation, you can use `$post->category`.  Since the relation is not yet loaded, it will get it for you when you do this.

Or you can eager load it by using the following `$post->load('category')` although this doesn't really benefit you because you are working with a single `Post` at this point.  If you had a collection of `Post` objects, then you'd start seeing the benefits of using `$posts->load('category')` otherwise you end up with the n + 1 problem.

Consequently, if you use `$post->load('category')` and then `var_dump($post)`, you should see that the relation is no longer null.

Comment: So, basically, it´s better to just set the foreign instead of associating the models when I don´t make much use of collections and just some attributes, as in this case?
My aplication is a multisite CMS, I guess I´ll have as much pages where I´ll show only one post and it´s category as pages where all the posts are listed.. So what would you suggest me to do?

Comment: I would say in this case, it's better to just set the foreign key.  Otherwise you need to instantiate a new `Post` model with the attributes set, query for the `Category`, and then associate your `Category` to your `Post` which would ultimately result in more queries than necessary.